# 'tagClass' is undefined in bootstrap-tags-input

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-tags-input, jquery-tags-input

```
<input type="text" id="shareemail" name="shareemail" value="" data-role="tagsinput" />

$('input').on('itemAdded', function(event) {
    var test = event.item;
    var test2 = validateEmail(test);
    if(!test2){
        $('#shareemail').tagsinput({
          tagClass: 'label label-danger label-important'
        });
        debugger;
    }
});

function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}
```

I want to add some other class to tag if the tag is not a valid email as mentioned in the above code but tagClass is showing undefined. I am following bootstrap-tagsinput docs but its not working at my end.
Please let me know how I can fix this problem.

Comment: If anyone knows the issue please let me know about that.

Comment: Are you sure you are including everything correctly? When I test your code in Bootply using bootstrap-tagsinput v0.8.0 I do not receive any error related to `tagClass`.  I also don't get `if(!test2)` firing so everything is just labeled with `label-info`

Comment: @Robert Actually I want to add class "label-danger" if email address is not valid and my code is not working correctly.
Can you please look at this code again??